# Cell data not displayed by react-table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, undefined, cell, react-table

My data is not visible inside the react-table's cells:

```
import React, { useMemo } from 'react'
import { useTable } from 'react-table/dist/react-table.development'
import MOCK_DATA from '../mock/components/LandingTableMock.json'
import { COLUMNS } from './LandingTableColumns'
import '../static/styles/globalVar.css'

export const LandingTable = () => {
  
    const columns = useMemo(() => COLUMNS, [])
    const data = useMemo(() => MOCK_DATA, [])
    

    const tableInstance = useTable ({
        columns: columns, //columns: COLUMNS,
        data //data: MOCK_DATA
    })

    const { 
        getTableProps, 
        getTableBodyProps, 
        headerGroups, 
        rows, 
        prepareRow 
    } = tableInstance

    return (
        
        <table {...getTableProps()}>
            <thead>
                {
                    headerGroups.map((headerGroup) =>  (
                    <tr {...headerGroup.getHeaderGroupProps()}>
                        {
                            headerGroup.headers.map((column) => (
                                <th {...column.getHeaderProps()}> 
                                    {column.render('Header')}
                                </th>
                            )
                        )}
                    </tr>
                    ))
                }
            </thead>
            <tbody {...getTableBodyProps()}>
                {rows.map((row) => {
                    prepareRow(row)
                    return (
                        <tr {...row.getRowProps()}>
                            {row.cells.map( (cell) => {
                                return <td {...cell.getCellProps()}> {cell.render('Cell')}</td>
                            })}
                        </tr>
                    )
                })}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    )
}
```

I put a breakpoint to inspect the cells value and is undefined.
[image]

MOCK_DATA and COLUMNS are looking fine, it`s not an include problem. I moved them in the same file and it still does not work.

[image]

The result is a table with the right number of rows but empty cells:

[image]

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hson9BXU9F8&ab_channel=Codevolution) tutorial on youtube.

Comment: Can i see you columns file where you have defined columns?

Comment: This is it:https://pastecode.io/s/t65onfcc

Comment: your accessor spellings are wrong. you have missed one `s` . There are 2 `s` in accessor. Kindly check and let me know. If this is the issue and resolves I will post it as the answer then